# Placeholder and label in Angular 2 Material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I want to set a placeholder that disappears when the user is typing and an input-label that is always floated above the input exactly like in this codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjypdO

But I don't know how to achieve it with the newest verison of angular material.

**Update**

Since it is not yet supported by Angular Material I implemented a Workaround that simulates the desired behaviour:

HTML

```
<md-input-container [ngClass]="{ 'zip': zipPlaceholderActive }">
    <input mdInput [placeholder]="Zip" [ngModel]="zipValue" (focus)="removeDefaultValue()">
</md-input-container>
```

Typescript:

```
removeDefaultValue() {
    if (this.zipPlaceholderActive) {
        this.zipValue = '';
    }
    this.zipPlaceholderActive = false;
}
```

CSS:

```
.zip .mat-input-element {
    color: #999;
}
```

Comment: Please use `angularjs` for AngularJS as `angular` is reserved for Angular version 2+. This can confuse people wanting to help you

Comment: Hey, are you using Angular or AngularJS? You have mixed up syntax of the both

Comment: I'm using Angular 4. I don't want to mix it up but the only example I found was this AngularJS example. But I want to use Angular

Comment: `floatPlaceholder` is Angular specific, while `md-placeholder` and `class="md-no-float"` existed in AngularJS. Here's a working example with `floatPlaceholder`: https://plnkr.co/edit/HtLlTiN32RmhQ0Z1B10n?p=preview

Comment: This is not what I want to achieve. I don't want a value be written in the input but a Placeholder and a Label (but "label" is called placeholder in angular material so it's confusing)

Comment: I see, I don't think it's possible at the moment. But leave this question be open in case someone else has any ideas. `floatPlaceholder="always"` is probably the nearest option you have for now, but that will leave the placeholder blank and have the label only.

Comment: As I suspected, it does not currently work, but the official `material.io` guideline says that this behavior actually exists(maybe on Android only for now). I've submitted a feature request here: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4930

Answer (score 1):

This is closest I could come to the Codepen example of Placeholder. This example handles keyboard events too, so the placeholder comes back if the user erases all characters, and goes away if user starts typing again.

`ts:`

```
  food: string = "Enter a food name";
  showPlaceholder: boolean = true;

  removePlaceholder(){
    if(this.food == "Enter a food name"){
      this.food = "";
      this.showPlaceholder = false;
    }
  }

  viewPlaceholder(){
    if(this.food == ""){
      this.food = "Enter a food name";
      this.showPlaceholder = true;  
    }

  }
```

`html:`

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="Favorite food" 
         [(ngModel)]="food"
         [ngClass]="{'gray-text': showPlaceholder}"
         (focus)="removePlaceholder()"
         (keydown)="removePlaceholder()"
         (blur)="viewPlaceholder()"
         (keyup)="viewPlaceholder()">
</md-input-container>
```

`css:`

```
.gray-text{
  color: #999999;
}
```

Plunker [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/8ZtMgM2WFiYTXHE91B0Q?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace the placeholder when the field is empty and not focused (so when it is actually located where a placeholder should be), it can be achieved with CSS:

```
:host /deep/ :not(.mat-focused) .mat-input-placeholder.mat-empty {
    color: transparent;
}
:host /deep/ :not(.mat-focused) .mat-input-placeholder.mat-empty::before {
    content: "My custom placeholder";
    color: black;
}
```

And if you are ok using CSS variable, you can pass the placeholder value from the markup:

HTML:

```
<mat-input-container custom-placeholder="true" style="--custom-placeholder-text: 'Type terms…';">
    <input type="text" matInput name="searchText" placeholder="Query">
</mat-input-container>
```

SCSS:

```
:host /deep/ :not(.mat-focused)[custom-placeholder] {
    .mat-input-placeholder.mat-empty {
        color: transparent;
        &::before {
            content: var(--custom-placeholder-text);
            color: black;
        }
    }
}
```